# vuejs - pass scope templates down multiple child-levels

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a table with vue, and I use slots for customized formatting. F.e. the table (which is a component), uses a `thead`-component, where each `th` is a scoped/named-slot. Specifing a template for the slot only works from parent to child though (or so it seems - `vm.$scopedSlots` is empty for the `thead`-component).

This is the outline of what it looks like:

```
// in index.html
<my-table :data="data">
  <template name="col1-header" props="column">
    <th style="colour: blue;">{{ column.name }}</th>
  </template>
</my-table

// in my-table component
<template>
  <table>
    <my-thead :columns="columns">
    </my-thead>
    // tr: v-for over data
  </table>
</template>

// in my-thead component
<template>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <slot :name="column.name + '-header'" :item="column" v-for="column in columns">
        <th>{{ column.name }}</th>
      </slot>
    </tr>
  </thead
</template>
```

Using the `template` has no use, since it only seems to apply to `my-table` rather than `my-thead`. The only way to use the `slot`s defined in `my-thead` is if I add templates in the `my-table`-component, but I need to specify them outside of the component.

Is there a way to pass the template that gets specified when using `my-table` to the `my-thead` component? As I already mentioned, I tried using `vm.$scopedSlots`, but this property is read-only and can't be set on the `my-thead` component. I can access the `$scopedSlots` of the parent `vm` though. I also tried using `slot` and `template` in the `my-table`-component to somehow pass on the template to the child, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a [github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5151) for this problem. As per the comments, there are multiple ways of dealing with this:

Pass the slots to the child, by using a render function, as shown below, and setting the `scopedSlot` property, or by using a property to pass the `scopedSlots`, as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6ofnoyg6/4/). Or use the in version 2.2.0 added `provide/inject` mechanisms to set the scopedSlots (which I haven't tried yet).

```
render (h) {
  return h('child', {
    scopedSlots: this.$scopedSlots
  })
}
```